# How we can remove zenid, category id and product id in Zen Cart 1.3.9g

Tags: php, mysqli, url-rewriting, zen-cart

In Zen Cart, when I am clicking on category name and product name getting following URL which is not SEO friendly:

http://domain.com/shop/categoryname-c-1/?zenid=4o1kc4rcvpgvce24sg046cfhn0
http://domain.com/shop/productname-p-11.html?zenid=sqibb0fiq5137ojkj0pstpobq3

Please suggest a good solution. I tested with "Ceon URI Mapping" and "Ultimate SEO URLs".

Comment: What is "SEO friendly" in your opinion?

Comment: In SEO friendly URL should look like:
http://domain.com/shop/categoryname.html
http://domain.com/shop/productname.html

Comment: You get the zenid when the program can't assign a session ID to the user as is the case with robots and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using magic seo urls from http://www.inveostore.com/ for a while now and it works pretty good. it is a bit of overkill but with Zen Cart you do not have much choice. You do not have control over how the urls look though. It just builds it from the categories and the titles which seems to work good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that Admin>Configuration>Sessions "Prevent Spider Sessions" is set to true. This will prevent the zenid to be indexed as part of your URL's.

It works for me